# Interpreting accuracy graph for a LSTM model | Keyword Prediction

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have created a LSTM model for keyword prediction. I am using RMSE optimizer for training. I observe that the train and test accuracy *decreases at first* and then fluctuates without much difference in avg accuracy.
I am trying to understand two things here-

1. Why is the accuracy ( test and train ) decreasing at the start (epochs 0 -200). Also why isn't there any increasing trend in accuracy with number of epochs ( even with training dataset )
2. Why is there huge fluctuation with every epoch?

   [image: Test and train accuracy]

Any help will be appreciated.